# The simplest way to download file with existing path from jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I went through dozen of pages with question "How to download file from jQuery", but still didn't find the simple solution.

I have my jQuery with ajax inside:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/Home/SaveQBMatter",
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify({ 'Matters': result, 'originalRecords': originalRecords, 'originalHours': originalHours, 'excludedHours': excludedHours, 'totalHours': totalHours }),
     dataType: "json",
     traditional: true,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data) {
           if (data.status == "Success") {
                var DownloadableFile = data.message;

                //HERE I NEED TO DOWNLOAD FILE

                alert("Success! You will be redirect to the Home Page.");
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                window.location.href = url;
           } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
           }
     },
     error: function () {
           alert("An error has occured!!!");
     }
});
```

Here in `data.message` I'm getting back from Action `SaveQBMatter` FULL FILE PATH

What I need is simply let to my user download this file before redirecting. Any help please?

Note: I'm using ASP.NET MVC, if this information is needed

Comment: Open a new tab using the path to the file

Comment: It would be super great! if you can help me with iframe and cookies stuff...

Comment: What does data.message have? The URL or the actual contents of the file?

Comment: Basically, have the script that serves the file to the client set a cookie, then recursively check for the existence of said cookie. When it exists, the download is done and you can redirect.

Comment: @KevinB, file downloads dont stop, even if you navigate away from a page.

Comment: hmm.... Actually, there might be an easier way. I don't know if this will work, but, create an iframe, set it's src to the location of the file you want to download, append it to the body, then do the redirect. does it interrupt the download?

Comment: data.message contains URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this plugin for downloading the file: 
http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, upon a successful ajax call, do location.href = data.message; which as you said data.message is the full path to the file.  With that, it should download the file without redirecting the browser.  Also when you download the file, make sure you have the header force-download.

You can see more about forcing a download here:
http://www.symkat.com/force-download-with-http-headers

Then, do a setTimeout of lets say 1 to 2 seconds, you can tweak the timings to how you like it, to let the download initialize and redirect.  So your code would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/Home/SaveQBMatter",
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify({ 'Matters': result, 'originalRecords': originalRecords, 'originalHours': originalHours, 'excludedHours': excludedHours, 'totalHours': totalHours }),
     dataType: "json",
     traditional: true,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success: function (data) {
           if (data.status == "Success") {
                var DownloadableFile = data.message;

                location.href = DownloadableFile;

                setTimeout(function() {    
                    alert("Success! You will be redirect to the Home Page.");
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
                    window.location.href = url;
                }, 1000);
           } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
           }
     },
     error: function () {
           alert("An error has occured!!!");
     }
});
```

Comment: This code opens a windows with url as path to my file, but download didn't start..The address wasn't understood

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (c) isn't associated with any program.

Comment: If you can adjust the response of data.message to return the entire url path, it should work properly.  Like http://example.com/my/path/to/the/file.csv

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the URL in a new window, if not blocked by the users browser:

```
if (data.status == "Success") {
    window.open(data.message, "_blank")
```

If you have problems with the file opening instead of downloading, you can try sending a content disposition header from ASP like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.extension"
```

Comment: Where should I put {Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.extension"}

Comment: In ASP.NET, you should call the `AddHeader` method of the `Response` object: `(HttpContext.)Response.Headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.extension\"");`